# How can I know my university ip adress for phpmyadmin(xampp) for android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have worked on an android application which I linked it to phpmyadmin through xampp. I connected it using the dormitory WiFi. The application works when I used the same WiFi but when I used WiFi from elsewhere (e.g. Mobile, school) it doesn't work. So I guess outside network can't find my ip address because my dormitory WiFi is a subnet. How should I fix that? Or where can I find more information about this. Please help me.

Here is my code in Android Studio

[Android code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwCOS.jpg)

And here is 'ipconfig' from command-prompt

[ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu9Dr.jpg)

Ps. I'm so sorry I don't know how to attach the code.

Comment: Where is this XAMPP running. Is it running on your computer?

Comment: Yes. And I started 'Apache' and 'MySQL' already.

Answer (score 0):

Your university has you on a [private IP address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), which cannot be routed to from an external connection such as the internet.

What this means from a practical standpoint is that it's not possible (or at least, is rather difficult) to reach your machine from outside the network. There are some methods you might be able to use such as a VPN tunnel out of the campus network to some other host that you would then be able to access remotely, but as a practical matter it's better to assume you can't reach your computer from the internet. You may find a hosting provider a good means to have a publicly accessible server available